# Django admin - make all fields readonly

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I'm trying to make all fields readonly without listing them explicitly.

Something like:

```
class CustomAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_readonly_fields(self, request, obj=None):
        if request.user.is_superuser:
            return self.readonly_fields

        return self.fields
```

The problem is `CustomAdmin.fields` is not set at this point.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please check out this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343535/django-admin-make-a-field-read-only-when-modifying-obj-but-required-when-adding

Comment: None of the answers there answer my question - "... without listing them explicitly"

Comment: Hope this one helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7920371/whole-model-as-read-only

Comment: @Prateek Thanks for reminding me to update that answer ;-)

Comment: @DannyW.Adair: Mention not coz I will be using the updated answer very soon. But thanks for the useful post.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Careful, self.model._meta.fields are not necessarily the same fields that CustomAdmin has!

"All fields of the Admin" would look more like this:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.admin.utils import flatten_fieldsets

class CustomAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_readonly_fields(self, request, obj=None):
        if request.user.is_superuser:
            return self.readonly_fields

        if self.declared_fieldsets:
            return flatten_fieldsets(self.declared_fieldsets)
        else:
            return list(set(
                [field.name for field in self.opts.local_fields] +
                [field.name for field in self.opts.local_many_to_many]
            ))
```

Comment: Thanks this works great. Just had to remove the many_to_many because it makes it look weird (they're registered as inlines anyway and have their own permissions.  
This feels much safer then getting `model._meta`.

Comment: No worries. Careful if you ever have an m2m that's not an inline. Though it should make itself known :-)

Comment: Thank you. This is the most reasonable answer I found.

Comment: Note, this won't work with a mix of readonly fields and custom fieldsets.

Comment: What do you mean by custom fieldsets? If you declared fieldsets then all of the fields should be returned as readonly.

Comment: `declared_fieldsets` is deprecated since django 1.7 and will be removed in django 1.9; replacing it with `get_fieldsets(req,obj)` reaches recursion limit. also, `admin.util` is renamed to `admin.utils`

Comment: Seeing as `declared_fieldsets` is deprecated and not available anymore in Django 1.7, what's a good approach to it nowadays?

Comment: This worked for me with Django 1.10

`    def get_readonly_fields(self, request, obj=None):
        if request.user.is_superuser:
            return self.readonly_fields

        return list(set(
            [field.name for field in self.opts.local_fields] +
            [field.name for field in self.opts.local_many_to_many]
        ))`

Answer (score 76):

Since django 2.1, you can prevent editing, while allowing viewing, by returning `False` from the `ModelAdmin`'s `has_change_permission` method, like this:

```
class CustomAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def has_change_permission(self, request, obj=None):
        return False
```

(This will not work before django 2.1, as it will also deny permission to any user trying only to view.)

Comment: Such a beautiful and nice solution. Why not more up-votes?

Comment: @ErikKalkoken: this works [only since version 2.1 of django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/releases/2.1/#model-view-permission) where the [view permission](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.has_view_permission) was added.  Before then (so up to and including django 2.0), the solution suggested by this answer will make the admin site deny permission to all users trying to view the relevant model in the admin.  Agree that it's the neatest solution for recent django.

Comment: Great answer! For some applications, you might want to add `has_delete_permission` and `has_add_permission` methods too

Comment: Not that inlines can't be added

Answer (score 27):

Ok, now there's this:

```
class CustomAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_readonly_fields(self, request, obj=None):
        # ...

        return [f.name for f in self.model._meta.fields]
```

Still looking for a less ugly way.

Comment: Actually I found this elsewhere. And after upvoting your answer and adjusting it a bit to the version I used and tested in my code posted my own.

Comment: the if clause doesn't add anything to your question

Comment: True. It's just cleaner. Also, it doesn't do this: `AttributeError: type object 'NoneType' has no attribute '_meta'` when creating objects.

Comment: This does not include any extra fields (eg: with a custom form).

Answer (score 12):

You could iterate through the model meta fields:

```
def get_readonly_fields(self, request, obj=None):
    if obj:
        self.readonly_fields = [field.name for field in obj.__class__._meta.fields]
    return self.readonly_fields
```

Comment: When user try to create new object you have exception here: obj.__class__._meta.fields

Comment: Ok, i delete my answer, you really was first :)

Comment: @hedde you aren't entitled to the answer just because you wrote it first, and just because someone has the same approach doesn't mean they are copying you or deserve a downvote

Comment: Really appreciated. Nice answer !!

Comment: This does not include any extra fields (eg: with a custom form).

Answer (score 6):

For Inlines (Tab or Stack)

```
def get_readonly_fields(self, request, obj=None):
    fields = []
    for field in self.model._meta.get_all_field_names():
        if field != 'id':
            fields.append(field)
    return fields

def has_add_permission(self, request):
    return False
```

Comment: return [field for field in self.model._meta.get_all_field_names() if field != 'id']
### thanks YPREZ

Comment: The `self.model._meta.get_all_field_names()` methodology has been deprecated in Django 1.10+: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/meta/#migrating-from-the-old-api

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me with Django 1.10

```
def get_readonly_fields(self, request, obj=None):
    if request.user.is_superuser:
        return self.readonly_fields

    return list(set(
        [field.name for field in self.opts.local_fields] +
        [field.name for field in self.opts.local_many_to_many]
    ))
```

Answer (score 4):

If someone still lookign for better way, you can use it like this:

```
@admin.register(ClassName)
class ClassNameAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    readonly_fields = [field.name for field in ClassName._meta.fields]
```

ClassName is your Model class.

Comment: Thank you for coming back and posting this!

Answer (score 0):

My requirement was similar . I needed **only one** field to be shown as read-only . And this worked fine:

```
class ChoiceInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Choice
    extra = 1
    fields = ['choice_text', 'votes']
    readonly_fields = ['votes']

class QuestionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    #fields = ['pub_date', 'question_text']
    fieldsets = [
        (None, {'fields': ['question_text']}),
        ('Date Information', {'fields': ['pub_date']}),
    ]
    search_fields = ['question_text']


    inlines = [ChoiceInline]
```

**Refer**: C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py

Answer (score 0):

Say you have defined user_mode as;

```
Admin, Customers and Staff
```

If you'd like to deny a staff (and of course, customers) the privilege of deleting a customer, product, order etc...

Your code goes;

```
def get_readonly_fields(self, request: HttpRequest, obj=None):
    if request.user.user_mode != "Admin":
        return self.readonly_fields + ['user_mode']
    return super().get_readonly_fields(request, obj)
```

where user_mode = a model field holding the type of user.

N.B: my code uses "Pylance" (like typescript in JS)

Answer (score -1):

With get_fieldsets you get all fields from the form

```
def get_readonly_fields(self, request, obj=None):
    readonly = []
    for fs in self.get_fieldsets(request, obj):
        if len(fs) > 1:
            readonly += fs[1].get('fields', [])
    return readonly
```

Comment: calling `get_fieldsets()` inside `get_readonly_fields()` reaches recursion limit :(

Answer (score -1):

```
@admin.register(Hero)
class HeroAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin, ExportCsvMixin):
    ...
    readonly_fields = ["father", "mother", "spouse"]
```

reference : 
https://books.agiliq.com/projects/django-admin-cookbook/en/latest/changeview_readonly.html

Comment: Question was to get `all fields readonly without listing them explicitly`. Your answer suggest listing them explicitly.