# How to add readonly inline on django admin

Tags: python, django, admin

I am using django 1.4 and I have a many2many field, so when creating the admin site I wanted to add this field as an inline, here is some code:

```
class SummaryInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = ParserError.summaries.through


class MyClassAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('classifier', 'name', 'err_count', 'supported')
    fields = ('classifier', 'name', 'err_count', 'err_classifier', 'supported')
    inlines = (SummaryInline,)
    readonly_fields = ('classifier', 'err_count')
```

So my question is, how can I make the inline field readonly?

Answer (score 82, accepted):

After a while of trying to find the name I figured out thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13817525/django-admin-make-all-fields-readonly), so I checked the names at `self.opts.local_fields` and found the name of the middle table and added it to [`readonly_fields`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.readonly_fields), setting [`can_delete`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.InlineModelAdmin.can_delete) to False.

```
class SummaryInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = ParserError.summaries.through
    readonly_fields = ('myclasssummary',)
    can_delete = False
```

pretty simple but took me a while so I figured out it was a good idea to add it here.

Comment: I'm not sure you can/should use `can_delete = False`. You can use `def has_delete_permission(self, request, obj=None): return False` instead. See docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/admin/

Comment: what is `myclasssummary` in the `readonly_fields`? is it table name or field name from `summaries` model?

Comment: @tamarabyte answer worked for me, not this one. Maybe change the accepted answer ?

Comment: @RustamGuliev I can't see anything in the documentation that says `can_delete` shouldn't be used.

Answer (score 50):

Additionally, if you do not want the ability to add/delete the rows, you can add these definitions.

```
def has_add_permission(self, request, obj=None):
    return False

def has_delete_permission(self, request, obj=None):
    return False
```

Comment: Add these functions below `class SummaryInline(admin.TabularInline):`

Answer (score 40):

You can make the entire inline readonly by adding:

```
class UnitsInline(admin.TabularInline):

    def has_change_permission(self, request, obj=None):
        return False
```

This will prevent anyone from editing the entry from the admin.

Another example that prevents, adding, deletion and displays all the inline fields as readonly:

```
class ReadOnlyInline(admin.TabularInline):
    def has_change_permission(self, request, obj=None):
        return False

    def has_add_permission(self, request, obj=None):
        return False

    def has_delete_permission(self, request, obj=None):
        return False

    def get_readonly_fields(self, request, obj=None):
        return list(super().get_fields(request, obj))
```

Comment: I'm using django 1.11 and this causes no related records to show. I guess because I can't edit them?

Comment: You'll have to add whatever fields you want to show up for the inline as readonly fields. I'll update my answer with an example.

Comment: For me, this prevents the inline from being rendered even for folks that have those permissions.

Comment: This worked for me, but the `get_readonly_fields` was not required. Also make sure you specify `model`.

Comment: @Matt I'm also using 1.11 and have the same problem. If I'm not mistaken, I believe this was fixed last year with this ticket in a much newer version of Django -- https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/31867

Answer (score 5):

Thanks Keval Prabhu

```
class UnitsInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Units
    extra = 0
    verbose_name = 'Units'
    verbose_name_plural = 'Units of company'
    
    def has_add_permission(self, request, obj=None):
        return False
    def has_delete_permission(self, request, obj=None):
        return False
```

Comment: Why is ** for has_add_permission, it throws an error for me

Comment: he was trying to bold. Ignore the `**`