# Using get_readonly_fields in the admin for a model with a @property

Tags: django, django-admin

I'm flummoxed by the following:

models.py

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    ...
    @property
    def xyz(self):
        return ...
```

admin.py:

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    readonly_fields = ("xyz",)
    ...
    def get_readonly_fields(self, request, obj=None):
        """ As per http://stackoverflow.com/a/13818017/1149759 """
        if <some condition>:
            return [f.name for f in self.model._meta.fields]
        return self.readonly_fields
```

If `<some condition>` is satisfied, the admin page for this model fails with:

```
Unknown field(s) (xyz) specified for MyModel. 
Check fields/fieldsets/exclude attributes of class MyModel.
```

I tried refactoring the model and admin code to make xyz() not a property, but this same error happened in the same way.

Even tried stepping through the internal Django code.  It's failing on this line:

```
lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py(640)get_form()
-> return modelform_factory(self.model, **defaults)

{'fields': [..., 'xyz', ...], 
  'formfield_callback': <functools.partial object at 0x104a024c8>, 
  'form': <class 'django.forms.widgets.ModelForm'>, 
  'exclude': [<a long list of fields that does not include xyz>]}
```

### Update

- Removing `xyz` from `readonly_fields` doesn't fix things
- Tried eliminating `readonly_fields` altogether as per comment below.  The following also did not work:

  ```
  def get_readonly_fields(self, request, obj=None):
      if <whatever>:
          return [f.name for f in self.model._meta.fields]
      return ['xyz', ...]
  ```

**After additional testing, it begins to seem to me that there is no way that `get_readonly_fields` will work on this model!**

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    # readonly_fields = ("xyz",) # Removed this field to test
    ...
    def get_readonly_fields(self, request, obj=None):
        return [] # Removed all the logic
```

The preceding *still* throws the `Unknown fields specified` for `xyz` -- as well as for the following two fields on the model!

```
added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True, blank=True,)
last_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, null=True, blank=True,)
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems the only way to get this to work is to explicitly add `xyz` to the list of read-only fields.

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    readonly_fields = ("xyz", ...)
    ...
    def get_readonly_fields(self, request, obj=None):
        if <condition>:
            ro = [f.name for f in self.model._meta.fields]
            ro.append('xyz') # <=============
            return ro
        return self.readonly_fields
```

Answer (score 0):

Properties are different from fields. You've defined xyz as a property, which is not supported as editable by the Django Admin. Only fields on the model can be members of the readonly_fields property of your admin. You should find that xyz is not a member of `self.model._meta.fields` and thus would never be returned by `get_readonly_fields`.

You should also include *either* `readonly_fields` or `get_readonly_fields`.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts, although they did not lead to a resolution.  Please see the updates above. Thanks!

Comment: Just want to clarify - when you return ["added"] from `get_only_fields` do you still get an error? I just want to make sure you're not mixing up properties and fields. You should be able to included "added" or "last_updated" in the list returned by `get_readonly_fields`. If you still get the error with those fields, I can dig into this a bit further for you