# Ignore inline model when saving

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I've been looking on the documentation and stackoverflow/forums for a way to ignore the inline children of a model when I save it in django admin. I've been searching for a few days and I can't seem to find an answer.

I have a normal tabularinline object:

```
class UserOrdersAdmin(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Order
    classes = ['collapse']
```

And a normal User admin registration:

```
class UserAdmin(BaseUserAdmin):
    inlines = (UserOrdersAdmin, UserSettingsAdmin)

admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```

What I simply want is when I press save within the User "change view", it will ignore the inline "UserOrderAdmin" which is inline to UserAdmin.

Comment: From the question it is not entirely clear what you are trying to achieve. But I think you should look at the "extra", "max_num" and "readonly_fields" fields you can set on the Inline. Also take a look at the other fields: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-options

Comment: @jgadelange well I put all of the fields in the readonly_fields in UserOrderAdmin and it effectively does the job. However it really don't do what I wanted, which was to only save Parent, as it's most likely still trying to save the UserOrder at the same time.

I was hoping there was some easy way of making the entire inline model stop saving on parent save. If I add a new field to the model I have to go in and add it here as well. If you want to make it a proper answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your response on my comment I am getting the idea you want to show some extra information in the admin, that is not editable. This can be achieved using `readonly_fields` in the Inline, for completeness you should also set the `max_num` to 0, because otherwise you can add empty inlines.

You could enter all fields manually or use something like given in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42877484/2354734

The end result would look something like this.

```
class UserOrdersAdmin(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Order
    classes = ['collapse']
    max_num = 0

    def get_readonly_fields(self, request, obj=None):
        return list(set(
            [field.name for field in self.opts.local_fields] +
            [field.name for field in self.opts.local_many_to_many]
        ))
```

For completeness of the answer also a link to the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-options)

Comment: I'm getting a RecursionError with that function: "maximum recursion depth exceeded"

Comment: Hmmmm... I should check the code before putting it on here... Give me a moment...

Comment: Ah it is due to the fact that `get_fields` also calls `get_readonly_fields`. I added a link to another answer I found when searching for this.

Comment: that worked wonderfully! I guess I was searching with the wrong keywords in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
class UserOrdersAdmin(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Order
    classes = ['collapse']
    extra = 0
```