# readonly_fields function doesn't work in Django Admin with models tabularly inlined

Tags: python, django, django-models

`readonly_fields` function works properly when I use it with individual models, but it doesn't work with models which are `tabularly inlined`.

Could somebody help in understanding how to mark fields read only when we deal with models inlined to each other on `admin` page ?

Thanks.

Comment: **tabularly inlined** show us how you did

Comment: Do you want a field on the inline form to be read only? Or do you want the whole inline section on the parent form to be read only?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to set a readonly field on the inline, you can do:

```
class SomethingInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Something
    extra = 0
    readonly_fields = ('field1',)
```

---

If you want to make the entire inline formset readonly on the parent form, you can try this:

```
class SomethingInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Something
    extra = 0
    # Set all your fields here:
    readonly_fields = ('field1', 'field2', 'field3')

    # Or instead return all your fields here if this should be conditional:
    def get_readonly_fields(self, request, obj=None):
        return ('field1', 'field2', 'field3')

    def has_add_permission(self, request, obj=None):
        return False

    def has_delete_permission(self, request, obj=None):
        return False
```

In the last example it will still render all the values for existing inline items, but you cannot add/edit/remove from the interface. this would in effect make the entire formset readonly.

Note: I did not override `has_change_permission()` to return `False`, because that would prevent the existing items from being shown.

---

If you don't want to specify all your fields manually, implement `get_readonly_fields()` from one of the solutions here: [Django admin - make all fields readonly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13817525/django-admin-make-all-fields-readonly)