# Django admin class model issue

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

```
class TheList(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['name', 'age']
    actions = None
```

I want to see a list in admin panel as readonly. If I use the below method it will show a list of objects which then need to be clicked on in order to display the name and age.

```
readonly_fields = ['name', 'age']
```

I have tried using the below admin functions which didn’t fix the problem:

```
has_delete_permission 
has_add_permission
```

The list is still editable

I tried using this with list_display:

```
has_change_permission
```

that made the class not viewable in admin panel

I want it to be like list_display but readonly, is that even possible?

Comment: This answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13817525/django-admin-make-all-fields-readonly suggests has_change_permission should work for django > 2.1  - which version are you on?

Comment: @SamSparx 2.0.7